# DateTime object has a different time on different PCs

Tags: vb.net, datetime, utc

I have a `DateTime` object:

```
Dim MyDate As DateTime = New DateTime(2013, 11, 6, 8, 30, 0)
```

Next I have a `DataTable` where first column is type of `DateTime`. When I serialize this table to a binary file and later deserialize from file to `DataTable`, everything is OK.

My problem is that if I serialize this table with dates on a PC with different UTC (for example UTC+8), and deserialize this table on a PC with UTC+1, time is not 8:30 (as in snippet) but 1:30. Can you tell me how can I achive to have same time no matter what UTC is set on a PC? I tried also this:

```
Dim MyDate As DateTime = New DateTime(2013, 11, 6, 8, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)
```

Or:

```
MyDate.ToLocalTime()
```

And still nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you serialeze datetime the datetime is converted to equivalent utc time and offset is appended. so when you desearialize it on different utc different utc gets added.

The golden rule is always to use UTC(UTC time is same all over the world) and conversion should be dynamic.

Like datetime now = datetime.now.touniversal;

serialize now

desearialize now on any utc(which will be local equivalent)

Comment: When I convert time 8:30pm to UTC on my PC (UTC+1), I will have 7:30pm. If I deserialize this time on a different PC (UTC+8) I have 2:30am. I want to have 8:30 on both PCs

Comment: 8:30pm on (UTC+1) machine is different Time from 8:30pm on (UTC+8) machine. The only time format that remains constant over all time zone is UTC. So always save the time in UTC.

Comment: Yes, I just did it! But I had to do one more thing: DataColumn has a property DateTimeMode. This property is by default set to UndefindedLocal and this caused converting it to local time. I set it to UTC and now I can see same time no matter time zone. I know it is not a good solution because it carries wrong information about UTC but it does what I need.